# How to relate an s3 version to a git commit

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, versioning

I am populating an s3 bucket with a zip of my lambda function.

I have two aws accounts, one for prod and one for development, each one has a lambda that needs the a version of the zip.

Development will stay on the most recent version of the commit 99% of the time, prod will be pulled from a specific version.

**The question is: Is there a way to "tag" a version?**

Specifically, I would like some way to look at a version in the s3 bucket and be able to tell which git commit we were on when we submitted it.

Comment: Would checking out git tags help? https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging

Comment: @evolutionxbox, I don't think so... It seems like that would involve decompressing the zip and looking inside to find out what version applies to what commit (-If I'm understanding you correctly. If I'm not please elaborate on the suggestion more). Looking for a way to do it inside of aws.